# String interpolation in Python when it already contains curly brackets

Tags: python

I am preparing a GraphQL query string in Python, I need to interpolate three variables in the string, there is just one problem. GraphQL contains a lot of curly brackets and it interferes with the way Python f strings work.

```py
number = 10
owner = "me"
name = "my_repo"
query = f"""
query {
    repository(owner:"{owner}", name:"{repo}") {
      pullRequests(first: {number}) {
        edges {
          node {
            state
            merged
            createdAt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
"""
```

Code above raises SyntaxError. So I assume I need to drop using f strings altogether?
**Is there a way to still use f string in Python when it contains curly brackets unrelated to the interpolation?**

Comment: TL;DR: use `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace all `{` with `{{` and similarly replace all `}` with `}}` and then run your f string.

To escape the curly brackets you simply add another on in Python.
So for example:

```py
x=3
print(f'x={{{x}}}')
```

That would print `x={3}`.

Comment: Correct. Welcome to stackoverflow! :-)

Comment: thanks! Used it for ages, thought it's time I gave a little back! :)

Comment: I won't add another answer for this, but for the O.P.: if you have a lot of templates, and doubling all `{` would impair data readability, you can make use of a template package, like  "jinja2"  and have your JSON as jinja2 templates : `{name}` are left alone and `{{name }}` are used as replacement markups by default, and you get a lot more options like the ability to have templates in files, use simple loops and conditionals inside the templates themselves.

Comment: @jsbueno thanks! This indeed might end up being more readable.